# .js runs in Visual Studio Terminal, but not from Command Prompt via Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-prompt

index.js contains console.log('hello World');

When I use node to run this in the terminal within visual studio code it works. (returns hello World)
However when I attempt to run the file via node within the windows command prompt it fails.

Below is as it runs in the Visual Studio terminal:

```
PS C:\js-basics> node index.js
hello World
PS C:\js-basics>
```

This is the result from command prompt:

```
C:\Users\godbe>PS C:\js-basics> node index.js
'PS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What is the proper syntax I would need to enter into the command prompt to run index.js (reads 'hello world' to console)?

I am expecting hello world to log to console.

I have tried variations such as:

```
C:\Users\godbe>C:\js-basics node <index>.js
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Users\godbe>C:\js-basics $node index.js
'C:\js-basics' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: ... If you're in a directory called `c:\Users\godbe` just run `node index.js`. It looks like too much paste not enough cut.

Comment: C:\Users\godbe> node index.js

C:\Users\godbe>           @DaveNewton Thanks! but, It still fails to log 'hello world' to console.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're likely running a Powershell command in Command Prompt. Notice how 'PS' appears; that indicates that its a Powershell command.

Try to open 'Command Prompt' and then execute your command (`node idex.js`) in the directory.

---

Update:

You need to execute the command in the correct directory (i.e. C:\js-basics) where the index.js resides

To navigate to directory `C:\js-basics`, you need to first run the command `cd C:\js-basics`

Comment: I've exited the power shell. running   C:\Users\godbe>node index.js     
which returns no console log.  I also tried               C:\Users\godbe>C:\js-basics> node index.js
'C:\js-basics' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Seems like `index.js` is in `C:\js-basics`? You will first have to navigate to that directory using `cd C:\js-basics' and then run your command